# karate.prevRequest is null when accessing from a method in config file

Tags: karate

We wanted to write some log(s) when there are failures, we observed karate.prevRequest works well within a feature file but returns null when we access prevRequest from a method in config object.
Is it expected? Is there a workaround to get the last request details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `karate-config.js` the value of `karate` is static, and maybe if you wrap it in a `function(){}` it may work. Else I would give this up, I really don't understand what is missing in the existing reports that you need to do all this. Are you testing or trying to create pretty reports :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.We have been asked to log the error URL along with the assertion failure at the end of jenkins log

Comment: @MuhilR please tell whoever asked you that I feel this is a complete waste of time